# Как полностью удалить значение массива в Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase-database

Я создал массив в базе данных. Через код приложения я хочу получать значение из массива и  удалить его и БД, чтобы код работа надо, чтобы значение было полностью удалено, то есть массив должен начинаться снова с «0», но с помощью команды removeValue () он просто присваивает ноль. Как я могу удалить значение из базы данных?

Код программы:

```java
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mButtonSee;
    TextView mTextViewPromo;

    DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mPromoRef =                 
mRef.child("delivery").child("0").child("promokod");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButtonSee = findViewById(R.id.buttonSee);
        mTextViewPromo = findViewById(R.id.promo);

        mButtonSee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mPromoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    mTextViewPromo.setText(text);
                    mPromoRef.removeValue();
                }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }

                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

В результате я хочу получить значение из первого массива, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, затем удалить его, чтобы снова получить значение из нового первого массива.

Моя БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я обращался в англоязычный форум, там один человек предложил изменить код на такой:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button mButtonSee;
TextView mTextViewPromo;


DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mPromoRef = mRef.child("delivery");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mButtonSee = findViewById(R.id.buttonSee);
    mTextViewPromo = findViewById(R.id.promo);


    mButtonSee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mPromoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    LinkedList<String> values = new LinkedList<>();
                    boolean isFirst = true;
                    for (DataSnapshot codeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (isFirst) {
                            isFirst = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            String text = codeSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                            values.add(text);
                        }
                    }
                    mPromoRef.setValue(values);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }

            });

        }
    });

}
}
```

но теперь выскакивает ошибка при нажатии на кнопку:

```
> 2019-02-22 21:33:43.502 4777-4777/com.example.ru.puddig
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.ru.puddig, PID: 4777
>     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:413)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:199)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:79)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:212)
>         at com.example.ru.puddig.MainActivity$1$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:54)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:183)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:75)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:63)
>         at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:55)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
> 2019-02-22 21:33:43.574 4777-4777/com.example.ru.puddig I/Process:
> Sending signal. PID: 4777 SIG: 9
```

Видимо парень из форума не выдержал моей глупости и молчит несколько дней)

Помогите разобраться в чем дело.
ссылка на англоверсию: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745930/how-to-completely-remove-the-value-from-the-firebase-realtime-database

Comment: Как вариант, можно просто присваивать массив с 0

Comment: Можно по-конкретней?